# How to assign value to each item in listView?

Tags: android, listview

I am working on health related app. In `ListView` I want to assign value to each item. For example `milk` contains `21 calories` so I want to assign `21` to `ListView` item `milk`.

Here is my activity code containing `ListView`.

```
public class FoodEntry extends AppCompatActivity {

// Array of strings...
String[] food = {"Naan","Pav bhaji","chole tikiya", "rice", "soybean", "milk", "curd"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_entry);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_item, food);
    ListView listViewFoodItems = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewFood);
    listViewFoodItems.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: You must use a Custom Adapter, to build your row, you can get some help [Here](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

Comment: I don't want custom listview i want to store particular value to each item in listview.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a String[] to store your data like you're doing here:

```
// Array of strings...
String[] food = {"Naan","Pav bhaji","chole tikiya", "rice", "soybean", "milk", "curd"};
```

Use a new object, such as CalorieCount.

```
// Array of CalorieCount
CalorieCount[] food = { new CalorieCount("Naan", 20) ... };
```

Comment: How to declare CalorieCount[] array ?

Comment: You could do it with the syntax above, separating each new CalorieCount() item with a comma.

Comment: `Can not resolve symbol CalorieCount` I am getting following error.

Comment: You need to create your own custom CalorieCount object.

Comment: As you suggest I am doing this `CalorieCount[] food = {new CalorieCount("Naan", 20), new CalorieCount("milk",21)};` How to make custom CalorieCount object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleAdapter` with `Hashmap`

```
foodItems= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
//create first item object
HashMap<String, String> item1= new HashMap<String, String>();

item1.put("name", "Naan");
item1.put("calories", "21");
foodItems.add(item1)//add multiple items like this

String[] from = { "name"};
// view id's to which data to be binded
int[] to = { R.id.name};

//Creating Adapter
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, foodItems,
        R.layout.activity_item, from, to);

//Setting Adapter to ListView
listViewFoodItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To know more visit [How SimpleAdapter Binds Hashmap Data to items of ListView](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/06/simpleadaper-bind-hashmap-listview.html)